# Firebase Triggers / PubSub / MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Cloud Functions to handle events, I have some topics that trigger an event such as a write to my document store.

What I would like to do is on a change to my doc store, notify any users interested in that change that there is fresh data.

For example, a news feed. If User A triggers an activity that is written to the store, User B should receive an update that such an activity has taken place, either an instruction to poll new data or just the new event object.

I do not want to use the Firebase Realtime DB as it is a requirement to use MongoDB, however, I believe as Firebase can hook into the events on Google Cloud Functions, I should be able to trigger this still using events?

Is this correct? So far in Firebase I can only find triggers around Realtime DB..

I can sort of achieve this with FCM, however it feels like this is more aimed at giving the user notifications as it requires the user to accept them in the browser, where I want to notify the app itself, not the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I do not want to use the Firebase Realtime DB as it is a requirement to use MongoDB, however, I believe as Firebase can hook into the events on Google Cloud Functions, I should be able to trigger this still using events?**

Yes, but 
Using `only` Firebase storage triggers is a bit tricky thing to do, as Firebase gives you `a Single bucket` to work on, so if there is a change in FirebaseStorage(FS) the event will be triggered regardless of in which folder the file is stored.

**I can sort of achieve this with FCM, however it feels like this is more aimed at giving the user notifications as it requires the user to accept them in the browser, where I want to notify the app itself, not the user.**

Yes, you can use FCM for it, but you will need to store `FCM Token` of every device in some kind of database(If you dont want to store in Firebase Database) to send it to users.

**I want to notify the app itself, not the user.**

You can pass payload in FCM through `data` instead of `notification` which will be received in `onMessageReceived` and then you can decide what you want to do with it.

i.e.

```
var payload = {
  data: {
  score: "850",
  time: "2:45"
 }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was very helpful!

Comment: happy to know :)